# SAS 9.4 Macro Eval Function issues

Tags: sas

I have a data set called monthlypayments, which is located in a folder I have assigned ‘training’ and it has a variable payments.

I want to output ‘payment type’ which is “high payment” if the payment>400 and “low payment” otherwise.

I keep getting this error

> ERROR: DS-00075 : Parsing error occurred while trying to %EVAL an
>   expression: Invalid syntax found in call to %EVAL**

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
%LET root=D:\Users\Data;
libname training "&root.";

%LET dataset=training.monthlypayments;
%LET outlib=out;
%LET outfile=monthlypaymentsclassified;
%LET variable=payment;

%IF %EVAL(&VARIABLE.>400) %THEN %DO;
data &outlib..&outfile.;
       set &dataset.;
       paymenttype="high payment";
       run;
%ELSE %DO;
data &outlib..&outfile.;
       set &dataset.;
       paymenttype="low payment";
       run;
%END;
```

Comment: Why did you write a `%IF` statement when your problem description described something you would do with an `IF` or `WHERE` statement?

Comment: I was just passed this script to fix, im still just learning the basics of macro. So i should just have an If statement for the Eval function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to make a subset of the data based on values of the variables in the data then you need to use normal SAS code and not macro logic statements.  If looks like your macro variable just tells you which data step variable to use in your IF statement.

```
data &outlib..&outfile.;
  set &dataset.;
  if &variable > 400 then paymenttype="high payment";
  else paymenttype="low payment";
run;
```

Comment: Ah! Perfect. I understand